Best way to extract PyTorch sub-tensors from larger tensor using known shapes
For some context, I have created a PyTorch Module that originally output a nested_tensor in its forward method. However, it seems that nested tensors cannot be exported to an ONNX version of the model. Therefore, I've changed the module to convert the nested tensor to a standard Tensor that is zero padded via to_padded_tensor, which I output along with a tensor that contains the shapes of each item that was in the original nested tensor, e.g.,
import torch

# an example nested tensor
nested = torch.nested.as_nested_tensor(
    [torch.randn(3, 4, 5), torch.randn(6, 7, 8)],
)

# get the shapes
shapes = torch.tensor([t.shape for t in nested])

# padded version of nested
padded = torch.nested.to_padded_tensor(nested, 0.0)

So, what I want to ask is, what is the best way to extract the original tensors from the now padded tensor based on having the original shapes stored in shapes?
One way I have thought to do this is using multiple calls to torch.narrow, e.g.:
def narrow(t, shape):
    for i, s in enumerate(shape):
        t = torch.narrow(t, i, 0, s)

    return t

originals = [
    narrow(padded[i], shapes[i])
    for i in range(padded.shape[0])
]

This seems a bit clunky, so is there a better and more efficient way to achieve the same thing? It would be useful to have a solution that works for when the number of dimensions of the tensors within the nested tensor can be arbitrary, i.e., it doesn't hardcode in an assumed number of dimensions.
